# How to match a json field to a string - java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have the following `json` file:

```
{
    "path": [
        {
            "name": "account",
            "scopes": ["servicegroup_4", "servicegroup_5"]
        },
        {
            "name": "identity",
            "scopes": ["servicegroup_1"]
        }
    ]
}
```

a `String microservice = "account"` 
and an array `String[] scopeJWT = {"servicegroup_4", "servicegroup_5"}`.

What I'd like to do is loop over the `json`, find the `name` that matches to the `String microservice`value and loop over the corresponding `scopes` array. If one of the element of the the  `String[] scopeJWT` array is equal to at least one on the element of the `scopes` array, an `OK` will be printed out in the console; otherwise a `KO`.

So, in this specific case, an `OK` will be printed because the `scopes` array of `account` contains at least one of the element of the `scopeJWT` array.

Here is my code using `or.json.simple` library:

```
        String microservice = "account";

        String[] scopesJWT = {"servicegroup_4", "servicegroup_5"};

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\r.spampinato\\Desktop\\test.json"));
        JSONArray paths = (JSONArray) json.get("path");
        Iterator<JSONObject> itPath = paths.iterator();
        while (itPath.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject el = itPath.next();
            String name = el.get("name").toString();

            JSONArray scopes = (JSONArray) el.get("scopes");

            boolean isOK = false;
            if (name.contains(microservice)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < scopes.size(); i++) {
                    for (String element : scopesJWT) {
                        if (scopes.get(i).toString().contains(element)) {
                            System.out.println("OK");
                            isOK = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!isOK) {
                    System.err.println("KO");
                }
            }
```

It seems to work, but if I change the first element of the `scopeJWT`, a `KO` is printed, altough a `OK` should be printed.

Any idea?

Thank you guys.

EDIT: 
What about putting and `else` clause in case the name does not contain any element of `microservice`? I mean, in the first `if`

Comment: name.contains(microservice) right ?

Comment: @AarishRamesh Yeah man, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little changes and further optimisation

```
    String microservice = "account";

    String[] scopesJWT = {"servicegroup_4", "servicegroup_5"};

    // Store all the keys in HashSet
    Set<T> keysSet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(scopesJWT));

     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\r.spampinato\\Desktop\\test.json"));
    JSONArray paths = (JSONArray) json.get("path");
    Iterator<JSONObject> itPath = paths.iterator();
    while (itPath.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject el = itPath.next();
        String name = el.get("name").toString();

        JSONArray scopes = (JSONArray) el.get("scopes");

        if (name.contains(microservice)) {
            boolean ok = true;
            for (String element : scopesJWT) {
                    if (keysSet.contains(element)) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        ok = false; break;
                    }
                }
         ok == false? System.out.println("KO") : System.out.println("OK");
        }
```

}
This string array matching algorithm's runtime is O(N)

Comment: I do not understand this statement: `ok == false? System.out.println("KO") : System.out.println("OK");`

Comment: it's a conditional stmt in java. google it an understand. Please Mark it as right if it helps

Comment: `ok == false? System.out.println("KO") : System.out.println("OK");` does't compile.. This should be either `if(ok) System.out.println("OK"); else System.out.println("KO");`, or if you want to use a ternary-if it should be `System.out.println(ok ? "OK" : "KO");`. Apart from that it's a good answer though, so +1 from me.

Comment: Hmm, and I also think the `ok` should start at `false` and become `true` if one is found, shouldn't it?

Comment: the statement `Set<T> keysSet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(scopesJWT));` gives me errors like `the constructor HashSet<T> is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Is your break statement in the right place? Do you only want to break if you find a match?

```
if (name.contains(mcrsrvz)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < scopes.size(); i++) {
                for (String element : scopesJWT) {
                    if (scopes.get(i).toString().contains(element)) {
                        System.out.println("OK");
                        isOK = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isOK) {
                System.err.println("KO");
            }
        }
```

The break statement here will execute unconditionally after the first iteration of the for loop. So, if the first iteration of the loop matches, you'll set isOK to true and you'll see the result you expect.

If the first iteration doesn't match, you will still execute the break statement without checking any other members of the scopesJWT array.

Move the break statement to only happen when you set isOK to true and see if that improves things.

Comment: I do not know if the `break` statement is in the right place. I tried different place, but nothing. And to answer to your second question, I want to print an `OK` or `KO` and break

Comment: Although I think you're indeed right and the `break` should be inside the if-statement, since right now it stops always after the first iteration of the inner for-each loop over `scopesJWT`, the way you've worded it, it sounds more like a comment than an answer.. I also doubt that's the full fix for OP's problems however..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I did not understand the sense of your answer man. EDIT: Ok, my fault, I got you

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I tried this way, but in this case, 2 `OK` are printed out on the console.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the existing answer, your `break` should be inside the `if`-statement, otherwise it would always stop the for-each loop after the first iteration.

After that you mentioned the following:

> I tried this way, but in this case, 2 `OK` are printed out on the console.

So you basically want to break out of both nested loops after the first `OK` is printed. In that case you can use a label in front of your outer loop, and break that one:

```
scopesLoop: for (int i = 0; i < scopes.size(); i++) {
  for (String element : scopesJWT) {
    if (scopes.get(i).toString().contains(element)) {
      System.out.println("OK");
      isOK = true;
      break scopesLoop;
    }
  }
}

if (!isOK) {
  System.err.println("KO");
}
```

EDIT: A better alternative is to use [*@AarishRamesh*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225339/1682559) which only does a single loop instead of nested one, which is better for performance.

Comment: I did not think about `labels`, because I use them very rarely. Aniway, it works!!! Do you think it's the best solution?

Comment: @rico_spm Aarish' answer is probably slightly better since it only has a single loop instead of nested one, although his `ok == false? System.out.println("KO") : System.out.println("OK");` should be changed to `System.out.println(ok ? "OK ": "KO");` in order to compile..

Comment: What about putting and `else` clause in case the `name` does not contain any element of `microservice`?  I mean, in the first `if`

Answer (score 0):

a little change:
``

```
for (int i = 0; i < scopes.size(); i++) {
                    for (String element : scopesJWT) {
                        if (scopes.get(i).toString().contains(element)) {
                            System.out.println("OK");
                            isOK = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

``